Can you infer that non-significant variables in full model won't be chosen by stepwise regression methods?
I recently encountered this question twice, on my exam. If you fit a full MLR additive, model, can you infer that the insignificant predictors (p-value > 0.05 from lm output) will not be chosen during stepwise regression, such as forward selection. I said no both times. My reasoning is that forward selection only looks at the partial contributions of each predictors after each model size, so sometimtes the non-significant predictors on a full model, might be significant on their own such that its picked by forward selection. So you can't reasonably infer that non-significant predictors will not be chosen by forward selection?

The question is ill-posed, because "insignificant predictors" makes sense only in the context of the set of other predictors and "lm output" is too vague to be of any use at all, because it could refer to any of the possible models being selected from.

This is an ill-defined question; in general the answer is probably “no” because there are so many ways that we can induce pathological behavior (e.g. fix N and let p tend to infinity), but it really doesn’t make sense to talk about significance out of context

@whuber Thank you for responding! Do you guys meant the my post is ill-defined or the question is ill-defined? And could you explain to me what you meant by "lm output" to be vague? I also a bit unsure on what you meant by significance out of context? Sorry I'm trying to learn a bit more, because I honestly didnt think about significance out of context during the exam. It would be great it you could provide some clarification please.

@whuber By lm output, i meant the output that comes from running the R command, lm(y ~ x, data) for a full model with no interactions. So maybe what you meant by significance in the context of the set of other predictors, is that I can't really compare significance in a full model since its a result with other predictors, with foward selection which selects predictors one by one?

You may have predictors that have statistically significant effects in univariable models (that thus may be selected by stepwise regression), but non-significant effects in a multivariable model. This is particularly common in the case of correlated predictors

Do not use step-wise model selection

Also, you write "insignificant (p < 0.05)" but that is significant. Was that a typo?

Yes sorry, that was a typo

@alanocallaghan - might want to expand this point and write it up as an answer.
